# Can we use single ion-textarea to post comment and at the same time to reply a comment

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When I click on a reply button I am redirecting the focus to a text field which is already used for posting comment, now I want that textbox also post the reply
--When focusInput(input) is call, it focus to the text area which is in the footer--

```
  <button (click)="focusInput(input)" style="background-color:transparent">
      <p style="color:dodgerblue;font-size: 16px">Reply</p>
        </span></button>
  <ion-footer>
  <ion-list style="text-align: center">
  <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
      <ion-item text-wrap> 
            <ion-textarea  #input type="text" id="myInput1"  [(ngModel)]="body" placeholder="Write a Comment" spellcheck="true" autoComplete="true" autocorrect="true" autosize></ion-textarea>  
      </ion-item> 
      </ion-col>
      <button (click)="postComments(commentsList.id,i)" icon-only item-right class="send-chat-button" style="background-color: transparent">
      <ion-icon name="send" style="color:orange"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-list>


  //.ts file
     focusInput(input) {
      input.setFocus();
    }

    postComments() {
//console.log(this.userDetails)
let commentPost = {
  "post_id": this.commentsList.id,
  "body": this.body,
 "user" :{ "name":this.userDetails.name,"photo": {"file":this.userDetails.photo.file}},

}
this.service.postComment(commentPost)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.returndata = data;
    console.log(this.returndata)
   //this.commentsList.comment.push(this.returndata)
  })
  this.commentsList.comment.push(commentPost);
this.body = "";
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "text box also post the reply"? And how is the comment text area related to the text area in the footer?

Comment: if u see the insta app u can post your comment and reply from the same input feild in same wa i need